# Why is D missing container classes?

Tags: data-structures, d

I'm used to C++ STL containers. D has arrays, associative arrays, and strings, but where is the rest?  I know about `std.container`, but as far as I can tell it only has one container, the red-black tree, which I could use if I needed something similar to `std::set`.  But, what if I need a `list`?  Am I supposed to use an array instead?

`std::vector` -> `array`

`std::deque` -> `?`

`std::queue` -> `?`

`std::stack` -> `? maybe array and std.container functions ?`

`std::priority_queue` -> `BinaryHeap`

`std::list` -> `?`

`std::set` -> `std.container RedBlackTree`

`std::multiset` -> `?`

`std::unordered_set` -> `?`

`std::map` -> `associative arrays`

`std::multimap` -> `?`

`std::unordered_map` -> `?`

Are there any plans to support any of the missing?

Comment: `std.container` has a singly-linked list (`SList`).

Comment: For multimaps you can just use an associative array of arrays. For unordered sets you can use an associative array with a dummy value type (`bool` or `void[0]`). Note that associative arrays are unordered.

Comment: Deques, queues and stacks are trivially (but inefficiently) simulated with arrays and the slicing/concatenation operators.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe that the main holdup for getting more containers into std.container is that Andrei Alexandrescu has been sorting out how best to deal with custom allocators, and he wants to do that before implementing all of the sundry container types, because otherwise it's going to require a lot of code changes once he does.

In the interim, you have the built-in arrays and associative arrays, and std.container contains `Array` (which is essentially `std::vector`), `SList` (which is a singly-linked list), `RedBlackTree` (which can be used for any type of set or map which uses a tree - which is what the STL's various set and map types do), and `BinaryHeap`.

So, there's no question that the situation needs to be improved (and it will), but I don't know how soon. Eventually, std.container should have container types which correspond to all of the STL container types.

Comment: Allocators should be one of the next few things in the Phobos review queue, mainly because Andrei has already suggested a design and I've taken it and run with it for RegionAllocator, and also implemented a trivial wrapper around the GC allocator to prove that the design works with more than one allocation scheme.

Comment: What about [dcollections](http://dsource.org/projects/dcollections) as a temp solution ?

Comment: dcollections works just fine if you want to use it, but it's obviously not part of the standard library. It is a solid library however.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis is there a good reason why std.Array is a struct while std.RedBlackTree is a class?

Comment: Originally, all of std.container was going to be ref-counted structs, then it was going to be final classes. With the custom allocator stuff added, I'm not quite sure which we're going to get. Either `Array` or `RedBlackTree` could change in the future. `RedBlackTree` had been a struct and was converted to a class per the plan, not only because that was where we were going, but because there were issues with `RedBlackTree.init`. It just works better for it to be a class. But `Array` was never changed, and I don't know if it will be. It depends on what happens with the custom allocator design.

Comment: @dsimcha It's been a year and still no allocators!

Comment: @Arlen The review that he mentioned resulted in a lot of discussion and a change of plans with regards to how custom allocators are going to be handled. Andrei Alexandrescu has been working on a new design, but he's also been very busy, so it hasn't been finalized yet. It'll happen eventually (and hopefully sooner rather than later), but it's definitely slower than we'd like. It's what happens when one of the busiest contributors is the bottleneck. But this is something that we very much want to get right, so while slow is annoying, it's better that then getting stuck with a bad design.

Answer (score 10):

Containers are a todo in terms of library development in D, but noone's gotten a comprehensive container library into Phobos because noone agrees on what the design should be, and everyone who contributes to the standard library (which has been growing very rapidly) has found more interesting things to work on.

`std::vector` -> `array` as you say

`std::dequeue`, `std::queue`:  We don't have one yet, unfortunately.

`std::stack`:  This can be trivially implemented on top of `SList` or an array.

`std::set`:  This can be trivially implemented on top of either `RedBlackTree`.

`std::multiset`:  I think `RedBlackTree` can be set to allow duplicates.

`std::unordered_set`:  This can be trivially implemented on top of the builtin associative array.  To implement it on top of the builtin AA, use `byte[0][SomeType]`.

`std::map`:  Can be trivially implemented on top of `RedBlackTree`.

`std::multimap`:  You can probably use associative arrays of arrays for this.

`std__unordered_map`:  Use builtin associative arrays.

Comment: `std::dequeue` and `std::queue` --> `std.container.Array`.